# Standardize and rescale each column of every element in a list

Tags: r, list, lapply, standardized

I have a list of 5 dataframes like so:

```
mydf <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(21:25),z=rnorm(1:5), p=rnorm(2:6), f=rnorm(3:7))
mylist <- rep(list(mydf),5)
names(mylist) <-c("2006-01-01","2006-01-02","2006-01-03","2006-01-04","2006-01-05")
```

I also have a 3 step formula and following bits of code i put together:

[image]

Step 1 -  the code for this is as follows this needs to be calculated for every row of the same column. if x is an element of "z" , "f" or "p" then:

```
z = x - mean(column))/sd(column)
```

2 - rescale z scores from 0 using values from step 1

```
rz = abs(min(z)) + z
```

3 - Rescale RZ scores from step 2 such that they lie between 0 and 1

```
mrz = rz/max(rz)
```

I need to apply this formula **to columns "z", "p", "f" only** also `objective_col <- colnames(mylist$'2006-01-05'[,3:5])` in every element of `mylist` using `apply` , `sapply`, `lapply` or other type of loop:

it will probably look something like:

```
lapply(mylist, FUN = function(x) .......)
```

Outputs should be in the same layout and format as `mydf` all stored in `mylist2 <- list()`

I will continue to update this as i make more progress. I'm still learning how to use loops and functions..Thanks to anyone that can provide some input.

Comment: How do you define **rows z, p, f**? All I see are columns. Do you have a different variable that defines these subsets or is this just a typo?

Comment: it was a typo. gone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  x[, c("z", "p", "f")] <- apply(x[, c("z", "p", "f")], 2, function(y) {
    y2 <- scale(y)
    return((y2 + abs(min(y2))) / max(y2))    
  })
return(x)
})
```

Comment: You should be able to use `lapply` instead of `apply(...,2,FUN)`

Comment: sure, either works ... `lapply(x[[c("z", "p", "f")]], function(y) ...` as above

Comment: i also looked at the 'scale' function earlier. does it represent exactly (x-μ)/σ ? formula was not shown in documentation so i figured i'll take the safer route,. Thank you for the help. looks great.

Comment: well, technically, \mu and \sigma are unknown parameters. If you know their values (from the population), you can use them. `scale()` uses the MLE for \mu, \sigma (ie the sample mean and sample standard deviation.

Comment: @AlexBădoi - it gives the same results - test it: `all.equal(c(scale(1:10)),((1:10) - mean(1:10))/sd(1:10))`

Comment: @Alex - you seem to have included the last 2 steps into one line like so `return((y2 + abs(min(y2))) / max(y2))` . The last y2 ->  `max(y2)` is it rescaled from 0 in your code? The last step of my formula uses rescaled Zvalues. would it be correct if we divide by `((max(y2)+min(y2))` ?

Comment: actually `((max(y2)+min(y2))` would return just the `max` of `y2` which is the z score minus `min`. maybe divide by `max(y2 + abs(min(y2)))`

Comment: @AlexBădoi I suggest you walk through the steps individually for a single column. It would be useful for you to develop the intuition to be able to understand what the code is doing without having to run it... that is how to learn